# Delete the first entry only but keep the following duplicate entries in excel

Tags: excel

I have a large excel file with a lot of data.

I know how to delete the duplicate values but keep one value.

I need to learn another technique.

For example, a particular column repeats some data twice, some data thrice, and some data for four or five times.
I want to delete the first entry only. I don't want to delete the second, third or fourth entry. That means only the first entry or first data will be deleted, but all the second, third, fourth or the next entry will exist.

Will anybody please tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

This formula indicates if the current row is the first instance:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)=1
```

Put this formula in row 2 (assuming row 1 is header) and fill down.

The COUNTIF part counts all occurrences up until the current row, the addition =1 makes it a true/false statement.

This formula returns TRUE if it is the first instance or FALSE if it is duplicate.